# Axios-POST throws error after adding error catch: ReferenceError: axiosRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, axios

I've added an error logging to the catch function of my axios request. Ever since I did that I'm getting this [weird error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default):

```
03:21:09.131 Setting 1,2,3,4 on SER1 Visualization.vue:174
03:21:09.132 Object { pin: (4) […], port: "SER1" } Visualization.vue:179
03:21:09.413
Error pin is not defined Visualization.vue:211
    axiosRequest Visualization.vue:211
03:21:09.415 Test Visualization.vue:213
03:21:09.415
undefined Visualization.vue:214
    axiosRequest Visualization.vue:214
```

**Note:** The axios-post request is not successful. It's not due to the server, because when directly calling the axios.post from sendByte() it works.

EDIT: After rebuilding the code the error is gone. The error somehow persisted from a previous commit that got deleted again. Since I want to understand the error nevertheless I provided the code below

Here is the function that's doing the axios request:

```
axiosRequest(payload, path, request) {
      if (request === "POST") {
        axios
          .post(path, payload)
          .then(response => {
            console.debug(
              `${path}? \n Status-Code ${response.status} - ${response.data.status} [${pin}]@${port}`
            );
            this.response = response.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Error 
            if (error.response) {
              /*
               * The request was made and the server responded with a
               * status code that falls out of the range of 2xx
               */
              console.error(error.response.data);
              console.error(error.response.status);
              console.error(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
              /*
               * The request was made but no response was received, `error.request`
               * is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance
               * of http.ClientRequest in Node.js
               */
              console.error(error.request);
            } else {
              // Something happened in setting up the request and triggered an Error
              console.error("Error", error.message); // -> 211
            }
            console.debug("Test"); // -> 213
            console.error(error.config); // -> 214
          });
      }
```

And here the method from which I'm calling it:

```
sendByte(pin, port) {
      console.debug(`Setting ${pin} on ${port}`);
      var payload = {
        pin,
        port
      };
      console.debug(payload);
      this.axiosRequest(payload, this.paths.shift, "POST");
    },
```

**Can someone tell what this even means?**

Comment: Which is line 185 in `Visualization.vue`?

Comment: That's the beginning of the methods block: `methods: {` .. I've added line-numbers to the spot in the question now.

Comment: Are you sure the code you're looking at is the code that is running? The error message indicates line 185 should be within your `sendByte` method. I also cannot see `axiosRequest` anywhere in your code

Comment: That's because axiosRequest is not there. But just to make sure I'll rebuilt it with what I've provided.

Comment: Okay.. Appearantly something tripped here. After the rebuild the error is gone... But just for clarification: axiosRequest was indeed a function in a previous attempt to put all my axios requests into a function. Shall I provide that code?

Comment: I don't see the need. Sounds like you got into a state where _some_ of the running code was a different version to what you were looking at

Comment: I sort of want to figure this error out. I've put in the correct code now.

Comment: Like I said, _"some"_ of your running code was out of date but probably not all of it so you may have had an older part trying to reference `axiosRequest` but the part where it was defined didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was caused due to running code not being up-to-date with what I saw in the editor. Shouldn't trust hot-plug too much on my part.

After going back in the file history to the point where the axiosRequest function was still there, I've rebuilt and found the error in my code.

It was rather simple:

```
.then(response => {
            console.debug( // here is the Reference Error -> Fix: [${payload.pin}]@${payload.port}
              `${path}? \n Status-Code ${response.status} - ${response.data.status} [${pin}]@${port}`
            );
            this.response = response.data;
          })
```